# How to specify solib-absolute-prefix in launch.json when Using VSCode for remote debugging?

Tags: c++, gdb, embedded, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VSCode for remote debugging an ARM embedded system.
I need to use `set solib-absolute-prefix` to specify the SDK path. I now want to write it to launch.json and hope it will be set automatically when lauch gdb. But I  did not succeed.

I tried the following configuration. But when launch gdb, it will stop at ld.so, and the `step in`/`step out` buttons of VScode are gray-out, I can not use it.

```
"setupCommands": [
 {
   "description": "path for standard libraries",
   "text": "set solib-absolute-prefix path_to_my_sysroot",
   "ignoreFailures": true,
  }
],
```

After some search, I change to the following syntax. This time, the `step in`/`step out` buttons of VScode are enabled,but those libraries are not loaded correctly.

```
"setupCommands": [
 {
   "description": "path for standard libraries",
   "text": "-exec set solib-absolute-prefix path_to_my_sysroot",
   "ignoreFailures": true,
 }
],
```

Would you like to help me on how to configure it?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "description": "path for standard libraries",
        "text": "-gdb-set solib-absolute-prefix path_to_my_sysroot",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    }
]
```